# how to add points on a trapezoid side?

Tags: algorithm, math, vector, trigonometry

I know angle B, angle A, angle C, angle D and the lengths of AB, BC, CD & DA. I know length of BE, EF, FG.Then how can I get the coordinates of E, F, G. Also have coordinates of A,B,C,D. angle ABC is not right angle every time. It may vary according to the data containing. This need to be as vector as the model will rotate on the graph. BE, EF, FG & GC are definitely not equal lengths.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the coordinates of E, you can interpolate between B and C based upon relative lengths.

If B = (a,b) and C = (c,d), then the coordinates of E are going to be

```
(a + t*(c-a), b + t*(d-b))
```

where t is the ratio of the length BE over then length BC.

You can get F and G analogously.